# Swift: Referencing variables in one class from another function and/or class

Tags: swift, macos, class, variables

trying a few things out in Swift. I’m trying to get some things that seem muddled to me straightened out - mostly to do with how I deal with variables and referencing them in a project.

What I am trying to do is keep a variable (based on a struct) defined in ViewController accessed and updated from various other functions within an application.

So, a brief outline of the code I have is here. I actually wrote a smaller app to test my ideas out before applying them to something more complex.

I started in XCode with a Swift document based application for Mac OSX.

In ViewController.swift I have:

```
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var myText = "Hello, some text"

    @IBOutlet weak var textView1: NSTextField!

    @IBAction func Button1(_ sender: Any) {
        myText = "This is button 1 clicked"
        myText = setText( thisText: &myText )
        textView1.stringValue = myText
    }

    @IBAction func Button2(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Button 2")
        myText = "This is button 2 clicked"
        textView1.stringValue = myText
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.   
        textView1.stringValue = myText
    }

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        let document = self.view.window?.windowController?.document as! Document
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

In SetText.swift, I have this:

```
import Foundation

func setText( thisText: inout String) -> String {
    thisText = "Function"
    return thisText
}
```

I liked the idea of sending variables to the Set Text function and then returning it, but thinking about it more makes me think that actually this could end up like a proverbial bowl of spaghetti with functions calling functions and who know what else. So I was thinking that something like this would probably make more sense:

```
import Foundation

func setText( thisText: inout String) {
    let vc = ViewController()
    // Read the variable from View Controller
    var myTextHere = vc.myText
    myTextHere = myTextHere + " More text"

    // Set the variable in ViewController here
    vc.myText = myTextHere
}
```

From my reading around on this subject, if I call ViewController(), it will create anew instance of the view (is that right, or am I misreading?). That’s already happened, so what I need is to reference the ViewController that called the function setText, or rather that owns that particular instance of code. As I’m thinking about a document based application, I’d obviously want to keep all instances of myText with each document’s ViewController.

My aim is to create something a bit more complex, using a variable based on a Struct to keep everything together. So:

```
myCard.image // holds a bitmap image
myCard.size // holds the size of the image
```

And so on. being able to access it in the form of ViewController().myCard to both read and write to is what I am thinking I need to do.

What I don’t want to do is use global variables.

Thanks.

Comment: Try search for similar questions that have been already answered. There are a bazillion of them here.

Comment: You should take a look at Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns more specifically **singleton**.  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID177

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time seeing much correlation between the title of your question and the body of your question. In fact, I'm not even entirely sure that there's a question being asked. That said, I'll try to address the questions you appear to be asking (re-written how I think they're intended):

***When you initialize a new view controller, does it create a new view?***

Yes. There is a view property for every view controller, and it's not a shared component or a singleton or anything else like that. There is one main view for every view controller. It's almost certainly composed of dozens of other subviews, but there is one view that is ***the*** view for every view controller.

***Is there a way to get metadata about the state of a view controller from outside, preferably in the form of a struct?***

Absolutely. First, you'd need to define that `Card` struct. I'd recommend doing it in the same file as the view controller itself. You can define it outside of the view controller, or if you want stricter coupling and namespacing, you can do it inside the view controller. Just be aware that doing that latter would mean that the type name, when referenced outside the view controller, would be `ViewController.Card` rather than just `Card`.

Then you'd want to create either a computed property (`var card: Card`) or a method (`func card() -> Card`) on your view controller which builds and returns one of those based on the state. It sounds like you're already leaning toward the property approach.

Note: I would absolutely advise against having one that is a normal get/set property because then you'd have to constantly update it and modify it. The best thing to do is have a computed property which builds it on the fly. So when the property is called, it reaches into all your components to get the info you want (like image sizes, strings, etc) and then packages up and hands off the `Card` metadata struct. Doing it on-demand like this eliminates unnecessary complexity and consolidates the metadata logic into one place.

Some dangerous things in your code example:

- I can't think of a good reason to implement `viewDidAppear()` but not call `super.viewDidAppear()`. Unless you have an enormously compelling reason to leave that out (I honestly can't think of a single one), ***do not*** do so.
- I don't see any good reason for your first implementation of your `setText(thisText:)` method. The way you use it in your `Button1(_ sender: Any)` IBAction functionally does absolutely nothing. That method in general is screwy for several reasons: it's got an upper-case method name, sets the textView text by trying to assign to `stringValue` for some super strange reason, and does in three lines what could be done in one:

  `textView1.text = "This is button 1 clicked"`
- The second implementation of `setText(thisText:)` makes even less sense than the previous. The two biggest problems being 1) that you don't even use the `thisText` argument passed in, and 2) your method, which is called 'set text' is *creating a whole new view controller every single time it gets called*? That's a huge violation of "doing what it says on the tin." Methods should have a single responsibility and shouldn't do anything beyond that responsibility. I'd never in a million years look at a method called setText and think "I'll bet this initializes a view controller." Never.

I see this question has already been downvoted a bit (not by me), and I'd like to take a moment to coach you in using Stack Overflow: Ask clear, concise, specific questions about clear, concise, specific topics. As I said at the top of my answer, there doesn't appear to be a question anywhere in your post. I had to kind of make some up that I inferred from what you wrote.

Remember: coding isn't just wiggling your fingers while you think about an app. If you're doing the hard work of good engineering, you'll likely spend a ratio of about 10:1 (or more!) of staring at your screen to actually typing any code. Every time you write a line of code, you should be asking yourself, "Why am I writing this line of code? Is this necessary? Am I reinventing the wheel?)

Good luck!